# Error on blank row in my openvpn client config

Tags: linux, config, openvpn-connect

I try to connect client openvpn, but it shows me, there is error in config on blank row. Any ideas what could be wrong?

My test command is `openvpn client.conf` and i get error `Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/client.conf:9`

My client.conf is

```
remote validIPHere
float
nobind
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
keepalive 15 60

# for OpenVPN 2.4 or older
comp-lzo yes
# for OpenVPN 2.4 or newer
;compress lzo

auth-user-pass
client
auth SHA1
cipher AES-128-CBC
remote-cert-tls server
```

I tried delete all balnk rows, but then there is a timeout (after long time).

Thanks for help